# SignalR sending notification to a specific client it's not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

When sending a notification with SignalR to a specific user it's not working.

I'm storing connection IDs in a table and when the notification should be sent I get the connection ID for the receiver from the DB but he doesn't get anything. What is wrong with my code?

```
// get the connectionId of the receiver
if (_db.UserConnectionid != null)
{
    var userConn = await _db.UserConnectionid.Where(x => x.UserId == receiver).Select(x => x.ConnectionId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    //if the receiver is online
    if (userConn != null)
    {
        await Clients.Client(userConn).SendAsync("RecieveMessage", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have the UserId, you can directly try Clients.User(receiver).SendAsync(...)

Comment: Well this could be due to multiple different reasons, stale connection Ids in the DB or especially in the case of SPAs if you have created multiple connection objects in different pages and did not clean up and close those connections before leaving the page. the message you are sending will always be received by the object you created first. This has been the cause of most of my troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm storing connection IDs in a table and when the notification should be sent I get the connection ID for the receiver from the DB but he doesn't get anything. What is wrong with my code?

Firstly, please note that a user could have more than one connection id, to troubleshoot the issue, you can try to debug the code and make sure the connection id you retrieved from db is same as the one of current connecting user.

Besides, to send message to a specific user, you can try to get all stored connection id(s) of a specific user/receiver, then send message by specify connectionIds, like below.

```
var ConnectionIds = _db.UserConnectionid.Where(x => x.UserId == receiver).Select(x => x.ConnectionId).ToList();

if (ConnectionIds.Count > 0)
{
    await Clients.Clients(ConnectionIds).SendAsync("RecieveMessage", message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default user claims mechanism for authorization, you probably can take a look into this mechanism:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-claims-to-customize-identity-handling

If you will provide IUserIdProvider service or map userId to ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier claim, you will be able to filter your SignalR clients by stringified user id using this method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubclients-1.user?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_SignalR_IHubClients_1_User_System_String_

Like this:

```
await Clients.User(receiver.ToString()).SendAsync("RecieveMessage", message);
```

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in the article, don’t store Id’s.

https://consultwithgriff.com/signalr-connection-ids/